# Creating Multiple Groups of Data in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

Been scratching my head on this one, but I feel I'm overlooking the obvious answer, and none of my search phrases have lead to any results..  I am compiling the results of a survey in a database, in the following structure.

```
ID  TestName     Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4
--  ---------  ----  ----  ----  ----
1   test1        1     2     1     1
2   test1        2     3     4     1
3   test2        1     1     4     2
4   test1        2     5     3     4
5   test2        1     5     2     4
```

I want to group the similar results in each column, only if they have they share the same Name, and get a count from each similar result. My final output is shown below, but I am trying to find out how to write the query without having 4 separate queries.

```
Test 1
        Question 1 Results
        1(1)
        2(2)
        3(0)
        4(0)
        5(0)

        Question 2 Results
        1(0)
        2(1)
        3(1)
        4(0)
        5(1)

        Question 3 Results
        1(1)
        2(0)
        3(1)
        4(1)
        5(0)

        Question 4 Results
        1(2)
        2(0)
        3(0)
        4(1)
        5(0)

Test 2
        Question 1 Results
        1(2)
        2(0)
        3(0)
        4(0)
        5(0)

        Question 2 Results
        1(1)
        2(0)
        3(0)
        4(0)
        5(1)

        Question 3 Results
        1(0)
        2(1)
        3(0)
        4(1)
        5(0)

        Question 4 Results
        1(0)
        2(1)
        3(0)
        4(1)
        5(0)
```

Comment: The expected output doesn't appear to match the example data

Comment: I tried to make it more clear? Let me know if it still doesn't make sense. I'm having trouble because I'm eventually moving it into bar graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @YourTable table (
    id int,
    TestName varchar(10),
    q1 char(1),
    q2 char(1),
    q3 char(1),
    q4 char(1)
)

insert into @YourTable
    (id, TestName, q1, q2, q3, q4)
    select 1,'test1','1','2','1','1' union all
    select 2,'test1','2','3','4','1' union all
    select 3,'test2','1','1','4','2' union all
    select 4,'test1','2','5','3','4' union all
    select 5,'test2','1','5','2','4'

select TestName, 
       sum(case when q1 = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as [q1(1)],
       sum(case when q1 = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as [q1(2)],
       /* ... */
       sum(case when q4 = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as [q4(4)],      
       sum(case when q4 = '5' then 1 else 0 end) as [q4(5)]
    from @YourTable
    group by TestName
```

Comment: Getting the following error: 
yntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'sum(case when Question1 = '1' then 1 else 0 end)'.

Comment: @Patcouch22: Not sure why you'd get that error. I've edited my answer to include a test table to illustrate that the technique works. You should be able to cut/paste this code and run it yourself. Hopefully that will help you narrow down the error on your side.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
select name, sum(q1), sum(q2), sum(q3), sum(q4)
from tbl
group by name
```

if you're storing the q values as varchar, you can convert them to numeric before you sum them:

```
sum(cast(q1 as int))
```

Comment: This counts only the total number of rows, and doesn't group by similar answers.

Comment: don't the results match your output?  the trick is to group by your test name field

Comment: No, it ends up just displaying the total number of each TestName taken for each question.

Comment: sorry, you're right.  should have said to use the sum function

Comment: @Patcouch22 - Don't store numerical data as varchar for exactly this reason.